# StyleLint configuration to allow CSS hierarchical indentation

Tags: stylelint

On my Visual Studio 2022, I have the [hierarchical indentation](https://dailydotnettips.com/css-editor-hierarchical-indentation-in-visual-studio-2011-developer-preview/) turned on as my CSS formatter setting.

I wanted to run [StyleLint](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure/) on GitHub Action. How do I configure StyleLint so it accepts the hierarchical indentation as a valid CSS format?

Now, StyleLint complains about the indentation when the hierarchical indentation is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

You can [turn off the `indentation` rule](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure#rules):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "indentation": null
  }
}
```

As the built-in Stylelint rule does not support hierarchical indentation.

If you want to use Stylelint to enforce hierarchical indentation on GitHub Action, you'll need to [write a plugin](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins).